# css child div height is more than parent

Tags: html, css, frontend, antd

I am trying to implement an auto-scroll to bottom feature inside the `hasMessagesContainer`, however because the `hasMessagesContainer` is larger than its parent `messagePanel`, the `composeMessage` overlaps part of the `hasMessagesContainer`, affecting the auto-scroll.

The `hasMessagesContainer` has the same size as the `messagePanelContainer` rather than the `messagePanel` div.

```css
.messagePanelContainer{
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.messagePanel{
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.hasMessagesContainer{
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="messagePanelContainer">
   <div class="messageTitleContainer"></div>
   <div class="messagePanel">
      <div class="hasMessagesContainer">
         <div class="ant-collapse ant-collapse-borderless ant-collapse-icon-position-left">
         //this is an antd component that has multiple Panel component that displays the messages
         </div> 
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="composeMessage"></div>
</div>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You had a lot of error in your html, such as missing `"` or `>` I corrected as it is not the problem here. Here you are applying `height:100%` to all your elements but there is no fix height, so it is equal to not applying any height

Comment: It looks fine to me!? Since the title is empty, the message is covering the whole container.

Comment: thanks @MaxiGui, as I was converting `react-jss` style code to css. Hence sorry for the errors and confusion.

Comment: @EduDev, I am more concerned that the `composeMessage` is covering the `hasMessagesConstainer`. There are elements inside the `composeMessage` div that I have not copied over from my code

Comment: @nahsiloh It doesn't cover it if you have a look at your snippet here. Have a look at my coloured answer. Maybe the problem is within the code parts you did not post here!?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a fix height on your message container `hasMessagesContainer`, with units such as **px vh em rem**.

Then if replace in `hasMessagesContainer` your `height: 100%;` by `min-height: 100%;`.
Because if you keep the height 100%, with a color background, you will see it stopped by container size.

```css
.messagePanelContainer{
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.messagePanel{
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.hasMessagesContainer{
  padding: 5px;
  min-height: 100%;
  background: salmon;
}
```

```html
<div class="messagePanelContainer">
   <div class="messageTitleContainer"></div>
   <div class="messagePanel">
      <div class="hasMessagesContainer">
         <div class="ant-collapse ant-collapse-borderless ant-collapse-icon-position-left">
         //this is an antd component that has multiple Panel component that displays the messages
         <br><br>
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum id neque enim. Aliquam arcu nisi, molestie eu nunc a, ornare iaculis felis. Quisque a lectus eget mi sodales efficitur. Fusce pulvinar condimentum eros, a placerat elit elementum ut. Nunc lorem nisl, gravida a condimentum sed, iaculis venenatis ex. Donec dictum, lectus at ornare aliquam, tortor tellus accumsan turpis, sed placerat dolor mi quis nunc. Nam sed vehicula est, eget pharetra mi. Mauris sollicitudin ullamcorper purus, ac egestas quam euismod et. Pellentesque accumsan sit amet arcu sed volutpat. Cras pretium, eros et viverra scelerisque, tortor erat viverra nisl, malesuada aliquam risus arcu quis odio. In sit amet neque tristique metus fermentum bibendum non sed dolor. Fusce consectetur diam ac est sollicitudin, in scelerisque mauris auctor. Donec accumsan lorem et euismod volutpat. Phasellus sit amet lacus vulputate, porttitor velit tincidunt, varius tellus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
<br><br>
Nam a sapien efficitur, dictum ante ac, faucibus turpis. Nam tincidunt auctor nisi, ac mattis magna egestas a. Duis semper vestibulum mauris non hendrerit. Sed sed facilisis mi. Vestibulum dapibus, mauris dictum dictum dictum, diam arcu sollicitudin magna, non accumsan risus libero vel nunc. Integer in erat tristique, maximus odio quis, egestas tellus. Aliquam tincidunt nisi id diam congue tempus. Suspendisse et neque a purus mattis aliquet. Nullam nisi ligula, ultrices eleifend orci ut, sodales efficitur felis. Nullam pellentesque ex eu ultricies laoreet. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam tincidunt finibus mi in venenatis. Ut dapibus tellus risus, eget accumsan nisl venenatis venenatis. Nulla rutrum massa id elementum pharetra. Cras non laoreet arcu, nec congue turpis. Donec eu orci a felis porta viverra.
<br><br>
Vestibulum ut est ex. Suspendisse nec pretium ligula. Sed ut posuere nibh. Curabitur lectus est, luctus in metus id, imperdiet malesuada felis. Donec vehicula, neque suscipit venenatis auctor, enim nunc dictum urna, sed tincidunt lorem orci quis ipsum. Nulla vulputate ut justo sed placerat. Curabitur id rhoncus nisl. Praesent tortor nisi, consectetur sit amet sollicitudin sed, ullamcorper non massa.
         </div> 
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="composeMessage">
    <textarea placeholder="composeMessage" style="width:calc(100% - 8px); height:40px;"></textarea>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine. Doesn't it? Maybe the problem is within your other code correlating with it?

```css
.messagePanelContainer{
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ffdd00;
}

.messagePanel{
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background-color: #000;
}

.messageTitleContainer{
  background-color: #4089ff;
}

.hasMessagesContainer{
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #00ff88;
}
.composeMessage{
  background-color: #cf04ff;
}
```

```html
<div class="messagePanelContainer">
   <div class="messageTitleContainer">//title</div>
   <div class="messagePanel">
      <div class="hasMessagesContainer">
         <div class="ant-collapse ant-collapse-borderless ant-collapse-icon-position-left">
         //this is an antd component
         <br/>//that has multiple Panel component 
         <br/>//that displays the messages
         </div> 
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="composeMessage">//ComposeMessage</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put the scroll on your has messages container and position it absolutely inside the flex grow message panel:

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.messagePanelContainer {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.messagePanel {
  flex-grow: 1;
  position: relative;
}

.hasMessagesContainer {
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="messagePanelContainer">
  <div class="messageTitleContainer"></div>
  <div class="messagePanel">
    <div class="hasMessagesContainer">
      <div class="ant-collapse ant-collapse-borderless ant-collapse-icon-position-left">
        //this is an antd component that has multiple Panel component that displays the messages<br>
        //this is an antd component that has multiple Panel component that displays the messages<br>
        //this is an antd component that has multiple Panel component that displays the messages<br>
        //this is an antd component that has multiple Panel component that displays the messages<br>
        //this is an antd component that has multiple Panel component that displays the messages<br>
        //this is an antd component that has multiple Panel component that displays the messages<br>
        //this is an antd component that has multiple Panel component that displays the messages<br>
        //this is an antd component that has multiple Panel component that displays the messages<br>
        //this is an antd component that has multiple Panel component that displays the messages<br>
        //this is an antd component that has multiple Panel component that displays the messages<br>
        //this is an antd component that has multiple Panel component that displays the messages<br>
        //this is an antd component that has multiple Panel component that displays the messages<br>
        //this is an antd component that has multiple Panel component that displays the messages<br>
        //this is an antd component that has multiple Panel component that displays the messages<br>
        //this is an antd component that has multiple Panel component that displays the messages<br>
        //this is an antd component that has multiple Panel component that displays the messages<br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="composeMessage"></div>
</div>
```